# Were there any DeLoreans remaining after the end of BTTF3?

Tags: back-to-the-future

We saw that there were two DeLoreans in BTTF. One got destroyed by lightning (which was found in the shaft by Marty and repaired by 1955 Doc, but permanently destroyed later) but the other one was never seen since the end of BTTF1. What happened to the other DeLorean?

Comment: Isn’t the presumption that the Delorean from the end of the first movie the retrofitted one from the first movie? And is that not the same one later struck by lightning and so on? I’m confused by your question.

Comment: With an initial production run of 9,000, there are about 6,500 Deloreans remaining operational in 2021. There’s no reason to believe this isn’t the case for BttF, either.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Was that the same flux capacitor?  Or did he make a new one to put on the train?  Not sure how he could've acquired it since it was destroyed in 1985 while he was still trapped in 1885 - he wouldn't have access to that wreckage 100 years in the future, so he probably had to rebuild one from scratch.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Only after I'd had a night's sleep it popped into my head, you're right.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I've always assumed it was the same kind of thing as Tony Stark (movie version) building a 3" arc reactor with the same functionality as the original, which filled an entire building, while in an ill-equipped cave in Afghanistan.  After thinking about it some more the 2nd version can be much better than the 1st!

Answer (score 24):

Only one time machine DeLorean exists in the movie trilogy. Your confusion likely stems from the overlapping time traveling, creating [a big ball of wibbly-wobbly timey-whimy stuff](https://youtu.be/q2nNzNo_Xps). For example, at one point in 1955 that one car exists as four time-copies of itself at the same time:

1. Marty's copy, as seen in the first movie
2. Biff's copy, as seen in the second movie when he steals it to give his younger self the sports almanac
3. Doc and Marty's copy, as seen in the second movie when the Doc and Marty return to 1955 to try to prevent Biff from giving himself the almanac
4. Doc's copy, as seen in the third movie when 1885 Doc stored the DeLorean in the cave for his 1955 counterpart

All of this wibbly-wobbliness is resolved at the end of the third movie when the DeLorean is destroyed by the train.

Comment: So there are none left?

Comment: But BTTF features a timeline that *changes* as time travelers make new trips back in time, rather than a fixed history where whatever they did in the past was part of their history "all along" (I think to make sense of this you have to imagine a series of different versions of the timeline, which the viewer sees in order). So in the scene before Doc gets zapped back to 1885, I think there wouldn't have been a DeLorean in the mine at that moment--if Marty had been standing in the mine when Doc went back, I think he'd have seen the old DeLorean suddenly appear via the "ripple effect".

Comment: @Hypnosifl The way the timeline works is a bit inconsistent throughout. While the updating singular timeline is how most changes appear to operate, there is the major issue with why 2015 didn't change when Biff stole the car. Of course the fact that Biff was able to return to that same 2015 also doesn't support the multiple timeline theory either.

Comment: BTTF creators Bob Gale and Robert Zemeckis wrote an FAQ where they address that one, see [question 1.9](http://bttf.wikidot.com/official-bttf-faq#toc8). They say that when old Biff returned to 2015, it transformed to 2015-A (the future of 1985-A) around Marty & co., the same way that Doc said that 1985-A would transform back to a regular version of 1985 around Jennifer when they left her sleeping on the porch. They just didn't choose to make 2015-A look different than 2015 because it'd confuse the audience (maybe one could justify it using the timeline 'self-preservation' effect in 1.19)

Comment: @Hypnosifl Good point. I've removed the last line of my answer.

Comment: @user146309 That is correct. The one car is destroyed.

Answer (score 10):

The question is a seriously false premise.   The flying DeLorean of the trilogy is a future tech upgrade of the original. This is supported by the flying upgrades offered for sale in the future for any car.

However I feel it is worth pointing out the semicanon videogame sequel is based on the premise that the lightning strike created a time clone DeLorean.  The cinematic scenes from the game have been edited into films on YouTube.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future:_The_Game

Additionally in another semicanon continuity - the animated series features a new DeLorean time machine. Which truly is a second DeLorean and is much more advanced.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_(TV_series)

And per the question- both of these are after BTTF 3.

Comment: *"This is supported by the flying upgrades offered for sale in the future for any car."* It's also more directly supported by the story itself - it's right in the script (Marty reading 1955 Doc the letter from 1885 Doc) that the Doc had a hover conversion done on the DeLorean in the early 21st century.